# scanf doesn't work (integer)

Tags: c, scanf

When I execute my code, `scanf("%d", &n);` don't scan anything, I mean, if I introduce any number it doesn't do anything, regardless of the numbers I introduce.

```
void testEsPrimo() {
    int n; 

    printf("Comprobando si un número es o no primo\n");
    printf("Teclee un número entero: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%d", &n);  //<---- The problem ?

    if(esPrimo(n) == cierto){
        printf("%d es primo\n", n);
    }else{
        printf("%d NO es primo\n", n);
    }

    fflush(stdout);
}


Logico esPrimo(int n){
int divisor;
int esPrimox;
for(divisor = 2; sqrt(n); divisor++) {
    if(n <= 0) {
        return falso;
    } else {
        if(n%divisor == 0) {
            esPrimox = 0;
        } else {
            esPrimox =1;
        }
    }

}
if(esPrimox == 1) {
    return cierto;
}

return falso;
```

}

This is my esPrimo code that is about decide if a number is prime or not.

```
typedef enum {falso, cierto} Logico;
```

and this is Logico, defined in a .h file

PD: This are my first steps on C so my code might be bad.
PD2: Excuse me for my bad English I'm not native and my English isn't really good.

Comment: Not enough information. Your code doesn't seem to have any problems. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how do you know  it _doesn't_ scan? did you check the return value of `scanf()`?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the input that doesn't work? And what do you mean mean that it "doesn't do anything"? That the `scanf` call doesn't return? Have you checked what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns?

Comment: why are you even using fflush(stdout) here?

Comment: @ZoeticPsyche his second printf doesnt put a \n, and since he want to output right away that sentence, he gotta flush.

Comment: well i tried and it works flawlessly!

Comment: Does `esPrimo()` return, if so what is printed? Perhaps you entered a large number and `esPrimo()` is taking a long time, or is faulty.

Comment: As others have said, how do you know nothing is being scanned? You aren't checking the result of `scanf` and you haven't shown us `esPrimo()`. `cierto` is also undefined in your example.

Comment: Add `printf("scanned %d\n", n);` right after the `scanf`line and you will probably see that the problem is not with `scanf` but rather with `esPrimo`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I tried this right after scanf and it still the same

Comment: do you press return after entering something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `scanf` is perfect.

I think that your mistake is the loop for from `esPrimo`. Actually you have an infinite loop, because `sqrt(n)` has always the same value and it isn't a boolean expression.

Change your loop:

```
for(divisor = 2; sqrt(n); divisor++) {
        if(n <= 0) {
            return falso;
        } else {
            if(n%divisor == 0) {
                esPrimox = 0;
            } else {
                esPrimox =1;
            }
        }

    }
```

for this:

```
 for(divisor = 2; divisor < sqrt(n); divisor++) {
            if(n <= 0) {
                return falso;
            } else {
                if(n%divisor == 0) {
                    esPrimox = 0;
                } else {
                    esPrimox =1;
                }
            }

        }
```

But then you have a problem when you know that your number is not prime: you have to finish the loop.
You can do this:

```
for(divisor = 2; divisor < sqrt(n); divisor++) {
            if(n <= 0) {
                return falso;
            } else {
                if(n%divisor == 0) {
                    esPrimox = 0;
                } else {
                    esPrimox =1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

But if you can avoid using `break`inside a loop for, don't use that.
With complicated algorithms you have a clean code with that, but when you read a loop for, usually your understand that the loop do a exactly number of iterations. If you have another flag to end the loop, use `while`.

```
While (divisor < sqrt(n) && esPrimox == 0){
            if(n <= 0) {
                return falso;
            } else {
                if(n%divisor == 0) {
                    esPrimox = 0;
                } else {
                    esPrimox =1;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main problems in esPrimo.

First, the for loop will not terminate:

```
for(divisor = 2; sqrt(n); divisor++) {
```

Change the condition to:

```
for(divisor = 2; divisor <= sqrt(n); divisor++) {
```

Second is in the logic. If you find that `n` is not a prime, you need to break the loop or the function will always return `true`. You could do it either with the `break` statement or by checking the value of `esPrimox` in the loop condition.

Here's how to do it using `break`:

```
for(divisor = 2; divisor <= sqrt(n); divisor++) {  /* fixed loop condition */
    if(n <= 0) {
        return falso;
    } else {
        if(n%divisor == 0) {
            esPrimox = 0;
            break;        /* break the loop */ 
        } else {
            esPrimox =1;
        }
    }
}
```